# Медленное выполнение операции DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (XXX,1)

Tags: sql-server

Информация о среде и версии sql:
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-GDR) (KB5029186) - 13.0.6435.1 (X64)   Jul 30 2023 19:53:42   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
Ядер 12
Объем физической памяти 256 ГБ (серверу 230)
Размер базы - 7 Тб

Готовлю пустую базу для разработчика. Очистка прошла за пару часов. Сжатие базы работает около 20 часов. Загрузка по дискам и по процессору - 3-4 процента.
Очистка, предварительно, удалила данные из таблиц, логи операций. Ожидаю в итоге после сжатия до 8-10 Гб.
Как убыстрить процесс?